# Configuring OS X L2TP VPN to use Certificate for IPSEC layer instead of Pre Shared Key

Tags: vpn, mac-osx-server, certificate, l2tp

I'm trying to setup a L2TP VPN on an OS X Snow Leopard Server setup, and have had success using a pre-shared key, however I would rather not rely on a simple string, and use a certificate instead.

Setting this up on the server side is seemingly easy, you simply select a certificate you have generated from the list, and hit apply, however when I try to use the certificate on the client side it fails.

I have exported the certificate into a P12 file, and then transferred to the client, and imported into the login keychain, however when I try to choose the certificate (from Network preferences, clicking Authentication Settings, then selecting Certificate and pressing Select) I am shown the following error:

**No machine certificates found**
Certificate authentication cannot be used because your keychain does not contain any suitable certificates. Use Keychain Access to import the certificate into your keychain. If you do not have the certificates required for authentication, contact your network administrator.

Unfortunately even when I try to generate a certificate where I override the defaults, ensure the DNS name etc are set properly this doesn't change.

When I select Certificate Authentication for the User Auth, and click Select the certificate for the server shows up there, but obviously this isn't where I need it to be available.

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106561/no-machine-certificates-found-when-adding-machine-certificate-into-vpn

Answer (score 1):

"I have exported the certificate into a P12 file, and then transferred to the client, and imported into the **login keychain**"

Try putting it in the System keychain. Let me know if that doesn't work.